# Django test runner cannot find non-default database connection

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing

My Django application runs fine, but I have a problem with Django's built-in unit testing. When running the Django test runner on an app using a database other than the default database I get an error:

```
python manage.py test qc
...      
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 179, in ensure_defaults
        raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
    ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection other_db doesn't exist
```

In settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_default',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'yyy',
        'HOST': os.environ["MYSQL_HOST"],
        'PORT': os.environ["MYSQL_PORT"],
    },
    'other_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_other',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'yyy',
        'HOST': os.environ["MYSQL_HOST"],
        'PORT': os.environ["MYSQL_PORT"],
    }
}
```

Maybe relevant, in routers.py:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

    if hints.has_key('model'):
        model = hints['model']

        if db == 'other_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'qc'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'qc':
            return False
        return None
    else:
        if db == 'other_db':
            return app_label == 'qc'
        elif app_label == 'qc':
            return False
```

The test case I am trying to run in qc/tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from qc.models import *

class HybridTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        baseA = MyModel.objects.create(id='A',name="NonName")
```

Django version: 1.9.8. Im am running inside a Docker with CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had overwritten the DATABASES dictionary in the settings.py file, in case of a test:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}}
```

After adding an memory database for the 'other_db' things worked again:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
                 'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}, 
                 'other_db': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
                }
```